# Can't Change Input Method when Launching App with Admin Privileges

Tags: macos, input, admin, macos-mojave, ime

I wrote a script using the Mac script editor on Mojave (10.14.15)

The script simply launches an application with Admin privileges:

```
on run
    do shell script ¬
        "/Applications/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App" user name "name" password "pw" with administrator privileges
    quit
end run
```

I then saved this as an application and am able to launch successfully using it.
However the application that I launch (Anki study software) can not change the input setting, which means I am unable to type in any language except the default system language. 
Note that making a similar application in script editor that launches without admin privileges works without issue,
ie:

```
on run
    do shell script ¬
        "/Applications/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App"
    quit
end run
```

This seems to be the case no matter the app I launch, I also tried launching Sublime Text and the same thing occurs.

The issue also happens when using sudo to launch an app from terminal. So it definitely seems to be an issue with trying to launch an app as root.

I am new to working with AppleScript and MacOS. It seems the fault is with launching the application with admin privileges though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not normal to run an app with admin privileges. It ends up in a somewhat different environment, besides the obvious. It's basically unsupported and the input method issue you've encountered is the least of what you're likely to hit. Why does this app need that? What is the bigger picture issue you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The application uses global hotkeys that work in any window.

Comment: I really think simply advising against doing something isn't really in the spirit of answering a question. There must be some way of doing this, that is the information I am interested in. I could for example think of running a script for the hotkeys that is separate from the application that would communicate with it through a local server or something. Which would allow the main application to be run without admin privileges. I'd like to hear more from people who want to share their knowledge about how the current problem before doing so though.

Comment: It was a comment and not an answer. There are two different things here at SO. Asking for additional information is key to providing useful answers. Sometimes what someone is trying to do really isn't possible. It's simply not true that "there must be some way of doing this". Using global hotkeys doesn't require admin privileges. That's the sort of info that my comment was intended to elicit. For example, nobody could possibly have suggested anything close to your scheme of separate apps based on your question.

Comment: I am running the keyboard python library https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ , when attempting to run the app, it raises an error and says it must be run as administrator, running it as administrator fixes the issue. Now if you are saying global hotkeys can be achieved without admin privileges then please post some resource that goes further into how to implement that, because I've only seen statements to the contrary during my time researching the issue.

Comment: I recommend that you open a question about what you're trying to do at a high level. That is, register global hot keys. Include your requirements and what sort of thing you need to do in response to the hot keys being pressed. What language or framework you are starting from (e.g. Python, Cocoa, Qt, whatever). The standard Mac API for registering hot keys is `RegisterEventHotKey()` (yes, still, even though it was originally a Carbon API). Search SO for that and you may find what you need is already answered. Your app will probably need to be approved for accessibility access by the user.